# Finding dates in Excel where multiple items within same field occurred

Tags: excel, filtering, excel-2010

Let's say in Column 1 you have dates and in Column 2 you have items that were sold.  I am trying to find occurrences of when specific criteria are hit in Column 2.  Example would be where you're looking for instances when Boneless Breast AND Pork Loin AND Chuck Roast were sold.  It's easy to filter Column 2 for these conditions and see the remaining dates, but this is manual and not scalable.  Additionally, it'd be ideally structured to result in (in the example below) return no results if you added "AND Hotdogs" because no date has all four of those. Similarly, it would return all three dates if you only searched for when Boneless Breast AND Pork Loin occurred.

| Date | Item |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | Boneless Breast |
| 1/1/2023 | Pork Loin |
| 1/1/2023 | Chuck Roast |
| 1/2/2023 | Boneless Breast |
| 1/2/2023 | Pork Loin |
| 1/2/2023 | Hotdogs |
| 1/3/2023 | Boneless Breast |
| 1/3/2023 | Pork Loin |
| 1/3/2023 | Chuck Roast |

I've tried concatenating fields, but this gets tricky in terms of the order of fields being combined and also the number of criteria being used.  Helper columns would also help, where Columns 3, 4, 5, and 6 all represent TRUE/FALSE for whether or not that item is found within that week and then I could combined UNIQUE and FILTER to return Column 1 for when those helper columns return TRUE.  The issue with that is that it adds a lot of columns and doesn't seem scalable.

Comment: Please explain how you will enter e.g. `AND Pork Loin AND Chuck Roast` into your formula (hard-coded, row ,column) and how should multiple dates be returned (single cell, row, column).

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pivot Table:

[image]

Jus take Dates into ROWS section, Item into FILTER section and ITEM again into VALUES SECTION. Make sure you set it up to **count** values.

Then in `Item` from FILTER section select the items you want to target (Boneless Breast AND Pork Loin AND Chuck Roast). Count how many values you've selected (3 in this case) and then apply a second filter on `Date` from ROWS section and **filter by values equal to 3** (3 because you've selected 3 items)

Remaining dates would be your expected output. Notice it returns only the dates where the 3 selected items were sold.

You just need to play with the filters. You can make different Pivot Tables at the same time from same source and you can update data if source data change with a single click.

Just as example, Let's check how many dates you've sold Boneless Breast AND Pork Loin

[image]

Check [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)